# Google Chrome doesn't render Google Web Fonts correctly

Tags: google-chrome, google-webfonts, google-font-api

I am using three Google Web Fonts:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Bad Script and Roboto are rendering correctly, but Roboto Condensed doesn't render in some places, instead there is Times New Roman.

There is no problem in CSS, because Google Chrome shows correct font-family at Matched CSS Rules.

In addition i cleared font cache in Windows and browser and reinstalled default fonts in Windows.

On another PC and in different browsers it renders correctly.

Is there anyone stuck with the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone noticed the same problem here: [Chrome for Android does not display Google webfonts correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984859/chrome-for-android-does-not-display-google-webfonts-correctly)

I noticed the problem as well today. The Google Web Fonts are simply not rendered by Chrome for Android on my Nexus 7 (Android 4.2.2), when integrated from Google directly. I also noticed the same problem on Chrome for MacOS X.

To get around this, you could simply download the fonts and convert them on http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ for web usage.

Comment: Thank you, sorry i didn't approve your answer earlier.
Looks like it is the only way to get around this bug.