# How to display the same font weight on pc and mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, fonts

I am trying to display the Google font [`Proxima Nova`](https://fonts.google.com/?query=proxima+nova) on my site implementing it by:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Proxima+Nova:400,600,700&subset=latin,latin-ext');
```

When I set the font-weight to 700, it displays well on both pc and Android chrome.

The problem is that, when I change the font weight to 600 (semi bold), on pc looks how it should, but on mobile it shows 700 (bold). I read that when a font weight doesn't exist, the browser selects automatically the nearest. Is it a loading issue? Is Android not loading the font weight 600?

---

**Edit:**

I noticed now that the uppercase **S** of Android has the two edges perfectly horizontal, while on pc, on all weights, they are at 45 degrees.

Now I'm thinking it isn't a loading problem anymore.

Maybe the font on google fonts is different between devices.

**Edit 2:**

Here are the screenshots.
[image: screenshots]

Am I blind or they are completely different?

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Might just be a rendering issue. Browsers will render fonts a bit differently. Pretty sure Proxima Nova should have all of the different thicknesses, so I'd expect 600 to look different than 700. I'd be interested in seeing screenshots though.

Comment: @abney317 Please take a look at the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be [a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=322658) with Chrome for Android's font handling of local fonts.

The font import generates something like this:

```
src: local('Proxima Nova Bold'), local('ProximaNova-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=FwZD7-Am2FI_-VOxaLDvvq2zGUau84_G&skey=470ea9b7edd795d7&v=v11) format('woff2');
```

Instead of falling back to url source, it just uses the default Android font as it's fallback ([Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto))

The solution would unfortunately be to just download the font and host it yourself and reference the font from that location. See [answer on another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14245184/391715)